# Printer Canon Pixma MX925 on 16.04

Tags: 16.04, printing, canon, pixma

I have a "Canon Pixma MX925" printer and run Ubuntu 16.04 on my computer.

How can I install and use this printer?

Comment: please [edit] your question, and ask the question in English

Comment: I don't own this printer, but on the Canon website you can download the Linux driver: https://www.canon-europe.com/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/inkjet/pixma_mx_series/mx925.aspx?type=drivers&language=EN&os=Linux%20(64-bit)
Also there are manuals to download which very likely help you installing the various components.

Comment: Note that the PPA mentioned in the accepted answer to the suggested duplicate has no packages for 16.04. Please try the other answers and [edit] your question if they do not work for you

Answer (score 1):

so go here http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100517002.html and click to download and SAVE what will be cnijfilter-mx920series-3.90-1-deb.tar.gz

You need to open a terminal; and paste the commands below in line by line, hitting the ENTER key after each paste: to find PASTE in the terminal, right-click at the text prompt .....

```
cd Downloads
tar -zxvf cnijfilter-mx920series-3.90-1-deb.tar.gz
cd cnijfilter-mx920series-3.90-1-deb
./install.sh
```

and that final command runs the install script; it will ask you for your sudo password but it does 2 things: 1) installs drivers and 2) registers the printer on lpadmin so it should all work